# Relative path to absolute with scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, scraper

I'm trying to crawl a forum for ultimately posts in threads that have links posted in them. Right now I'm just trying to scrape the users names of the posts. But I think there is a problem with the urls not being static.

```
spider.py

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class TextPostItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
    submitted = Field()


class RedditCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'post-spider'
    allowed_domains = ['flashback.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.flashback.org/t2637903']


    def parse(self, response):
        s = Selector(response)
        next_link = s.xpath('//a[@class="smallfont2"]//@href').extract()[0]
        if len(next_link):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(next_link)
        posts =   Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="posts"]/div[@class="alignc.p4.post"]')
        for post in posts:
            i = TextPostItem()
            i['title'] = post.xpath('tbody/tr[1]/td/span/text()').extract() [0]
            #i['url'] = post.xpath('div[2]/ul/li[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield i
```

Provide me the following error:

```
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /t2637903p2
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "join" the `response.url` with the relative url you've extracted using [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin):

```
from urlparse import urljoin

urljoin(response.url, next_link)
```

---

Also note that there is no need to instantiate a `Selector` object - you can use the `response.xpath()` shortcut directly:

```
def parse(self, response):
    next_link = response.xpath('//a[@class="smallfont2"]//@href').extract()[0]
    # ...
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I have seen similiar solutions with using "urljoin" before. But I dont understand how to use it in my code. Exactly where would that bit go?

Comment: @Jomasdf okay, use it when you are making a request: `yield self.make_requests_from_url(urljoin(response.url, next_link))`.

Comment: ah, I see. Thank you very much!